# how to fix broken /usr/bin/ld?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, cmake, sudo

I accidentally execute the following command

```
sudo cp libcuda.so /usr/bin/ld
```

because i thought /usr/bin/ld is a directory, and I believe my /usr/bin/ld is broken now, at present I cannot use `cmake` anymore, does anyone know how can I fix this? thanks!

System: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did my suggested fix work out?

Comment: sorry but no, it did not work, I just reinstalled the whole system

Comment: What does the command `sudo apt list binutils` show?

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to fix it would be to reinstall the package containing `/usr/bin/ld`.

```
sudo apt reinstall binutils
```